# object is not extensible error in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to update promo object with new field called colspan. But my bad luck that getting

Error:

uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property colspan, object is not extensible
    at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3160:1), :71:32)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3160:1), :66:35)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3160:1), :64:47)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3160:1), :62:23)
    at Promise ()
    at F (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.js:865:1), :35:28)
    at Object.modifyData (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3160:1), :48:12)

```
departmentIds.forEach(departmentId => {
          results[departmentId] = []
          departmentWiseResults[departmentId].forEach((promo, index) => {
            let tmpPromo = promo
            dateRanges.dateRanges.forEach(range => {
              let startedDateWeek = moment(promo.startDate).week()
              let endDateWeek = moment(promo.endDate).week()
              let startedYear = moment(promo.startDate).year()
              let endedYear = moment(promo.endDate).year()
              tmpPromo.colspan = 0
              if (range.startYear === startedYear && range.endYear === endedYear && range.weekNumber <= endDateWeek && range.weekNumber >= startedDateWeek) {
                tmpPromo.colspan++
              }
              departmentWiseResults[departmentId].splice(index, 1, tmpPromo)
              console.log('stareted:', startedDateWeek, endDateWeek, startedYear, endedYear, promo, tmpPromo, departmentWiseResults[departmentId])
            })
            console.log('promo after adding colspna:', promo)
            // if (isInRange(range, promo)) {
            //   console.log('for range', range.startDate, range.endDate)
            //   console.log('for promo', promo.id)
            //   console.log(
            //     'diff is',
            //     findWeekspan(range, dateRanges.dateRanges[dateRanges.dateRanges.length - 1], promo)
            //   )
            // // if (!promo.used) {
            // //   promo.used = true
            // //   results[departmentId]
            // // }
            // }
          })
        })
```

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: `let tmpPromo = Object.assign({colspan: 0}, promo)` ?

Comment: Thanks a Lot @RoyJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object `promo` has had extensibility turned off via [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) (or [`seal` or `freeze`](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/preventextensionssealandfreeze/)). That means you cannot add new properties to it. Instead, you can make a new copy of it with new properties. A convenient way to do this is with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
let tmpPromo = Object.assign({colspan: 0}, promo);
```

This starts with the anonymous object that defines `colspan`, copies properties from `promo` into it, and then returns the object (which we assign to `tmpPromo`).